# Allow but not request client certificate in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, google-chrome, websocket, client-certificates

I am building a service with both `https` and web socket secure APIs.

The `https` APIs are existing ones and we need client to send us a client certificate so I have this setting in Kestrel:

```
ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate
```

When I try to hit the service in browser, a pop up will be shown and let me pick a cert. This is expected but it is causing trouble for my web socket API in Chrome. There is a known issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=329884#c28.

Basically, since the service requests a client cert, there will be the pop up and when establish the wss connection, Chrome will make it fail.

I am thinking if I can have a way to config kestrel accept the client cert but DO NOT request it so the client will not pop up the window and not fail the wss request.

Comment: Could you pls check [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146868/oncertificatevalidated-not-running-self-signed-certificate-client-authenticati)?