# Unable to make web-request secured with self signed certificate from .NET core application inside AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, ssl-certificate

I have an .NET Core 3.1 application inside AWS Lambda and I am trying to make an HTTPS API call which has self signed certificate installed. While making API call with the help of HttpClient it is throwing error as can't verify the certificate.
I have tried implementing this callback solution -

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

I have also tried various HttpClientHandler options but nothing worked. I am ok to bypass the validation.

Comment: Forget about Lambda, is it working at your local machine?

Comment: @AnkushJain It is working from local machine. I am able to make http version of webrequest but not https from lambda.

Comment: Check this answer, first part **Recognizing client certificates** https://stackoverflow.com/a/68156897/1273882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solution worked for me -

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
    SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls13,
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => true
};
```

I needed to set Sslprotocols param specifically to TLS13 when trying to make API request from Lambda(linux). On windows machine it is perfectly working fine even without setting any params.