# How to publish a web application with self-signed certificate client authentication - ASP.NET Core and Kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, client-certificates

My application is configured as per the post below.

[OnCertificateValidated not running - Self-Signed Certificate Client Authentication - ASP.NET Core and Kestrel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146868/oncertificatevalidated-not-running-self-signed-certificate-client-authenticati)

Locally running in my Visual Studio I can make requests and validations of the digital certificate without any problems.

However, when I publish to a public URL (on a server with a domain and HTTPS configured) and try to make the connection I get HTTP ERROR 403.

On my server I created a CA with a self-signed certificate and I am signing the client certificates, which will send these certificates in the request.

I did all this configuration on my local development server and it worked perfectly, but when reproducing these steps in the production publication I am having problems.

First I tried to configure IIS on a Windows Server but it didn't work. Then I tried it on a Linux server via nginx and had the same error.

Comment: Hi,@Rafael,have you follwed this document to cinfigure iis?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis